# devServer public option in Webpack 5

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

In Webpack 4, I used to set the external network URL of the dev server as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    public: 'myapp.test:80'
  }
};
```

In the Webpack 5 docs however, I can't find this option. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this has been removed in favor of [client.webSocketURL](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#websocketurl).

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    client: {
      webSocketURL: 'auto://myapp.test:80/ws'
    }
  }
}
```

From the Vue CLI documentation:

> public, sockHost, sockPath, and sockPort options were removed in favor [of] client.webSocketURL option.

https://cli.vuejs.org/migrations/migrate-from-v4.html#vue-cli-service